# regular expressions - finding the position of a number and removing brackets around it

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm stuck. I tried it with regular expressions, but I guess I'm missing something. I'm working with JavaScript.

I have an input like:

```
(text [number]) the text that follows...
```

I want an output like:

```
[number] the text that follows...
```

I tried it with `substr`, but my problem is that I do not know the length of the text or number in the brackets. I guess I need the position of the beginning and ending of the number to work with a regEx.

Have you got an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regexes are the way to go — using JavaScript’s `replace` function, you don’t need to fiddle with the position of the number in the string.

Try this:

```
var geoff = '(text 694) the text that follows...';
var geoff_replaced = geoff.replace(/\([^0-9]* ([0-9]*)\)/, '$1');

# geoff_replaced will be "694 the text that follows...
```

I don’t do much JavaScript regex stuff, so I totally looked up the above on this guide to JavaScript regexes:

- http://www.evolt.org/node/36435

Answer (score 0):

It'd help to have a real example but I made one up...

Text:

```
(Some text 1234) some more text.
```

Regex:

```
^.+?(?<Number>\d+)\)(?<Text>.+)$
```

Replacement:

```
${Number}${Text}
```

Full example:

```
var fixedText = "(Some text 1234) some more text.".replace(/^.+?(?<Number>\d+)\)(?<Text>.+)$/, "${Number}${Text}");
```

Answer (score 0):

the regex that matches `(text [number]) the text that follows...` can be like:

```
"^\(.*?([0-9]*)\)(.*)$"
```

or you can just match the beginning (and the ending `)`) and remove it

```
"^(\(.*?)[0-9]*(\)).*$"
```